# Setting the Day of the week in Java doesnt seem to affect the day

Tags: java, calendar

So this issue I believe is simple enough that I can just give you three lines of code and the problem is likely my understanding of the date class.

```
    public DrawCalendar(GregorianCalendar date){

         date.setFirstDayOfWeek(GregorianCalendar.THURSDAY);
         System.out.print(date.get(GregorianCalendar.DAY_OF_WEEK));
```

My problem is that I BELIEVE I'm adjusting the starting day of the week, so today, by default is the 6th day of the week. If I change this to a random day or integer like THURSDAY I'm still getting that today is the 6th day of the week even when thursday is the 1st day of the week.

That is what I BELIEVE is happening, why would the print statement not be returning a different number based on the first day of the week which was adjusted just one line before it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Use getFirstDayOfWeek() method
System.out.println(calObj.getFirstDayOfWeek());
```

Comment: Well that seems obvious. Thank you. I guess I missed that get method.

Answer (score 2):

`setFirstDayOfWeek` typically is SUNDAY or MONDAY and influences the WEEK_OF_YEAR number. The DAY_OF_WEEK is simply MONDAY, TUESDAY, ...

Comment: So what are the days of the week? 0-6 or 1-7 and by default is Sunday the first day? I'm not sure I understand why the first day of the week would not change what day of the week it is.

Comment: The default first day of week is Locale dependent: `Calendar.getInstance(Locale.US)`. The constant value of SUNDAY follows C/Unix convention, and is "irrelevant". BTW GregorianCalendar is not really needed using Calendar.getInstance.

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure it's because:

```
date.setFirstDayOfWeek(GregorianCalendar.THURSDAY);
```

Is used to tell the class which day of the week should be used for date calculations involving weeks, while

```
date.get(GregorianCalendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);
```

Is getting the day of the week that the current object represents in time (since the current object represents a specific point in time).